# Count event occurrence and assign it to individuals according to date and place of interview

Tags: r, date, dataframe, count

I have two dataframes in R: `A.df` and `B.df`. The first contains N rows where each row is an event that happened in a certain date and place.

The second is a list of individuals that have been interviewed in a certain date and place.

For each individual, I would like to count the number of events that happened within a certain timeframe before the interview date in the same location of the individual's place of interview.

Let's say that the time frame is x days before the date of interview, and that I have computed that date and stored in the variable `xdaysbefore`.

Here below how the data frames look like

`A.df`

```
#Event     Date     Place
   1   2015-05-01     1    
   2   2015-03-11     1
   3   2015-07-04     2
   4   2015-05-10     3
```

`B.df`

```
#Individual  Date of Interview   Place   xdaysbefore
       1         2016-07-11        1       2014-09-11  
       2         2016-05-07        3       2014-07-04
       3         2016-08-09        2       2014-03-22
       4         2016-01-10        3       2014-09-17
```

Note that `Date`, `Date of Interview` and `xdaysbefore` are all in `Date R class`

How can I count for each individual in `B.df` the events happened within the time frame `Date of Interview - xdaysbefore` according to the place in which the event has happened and the individual place of interview.

What I would expect in `B.df` would look like this:

`B.df`

```
#Individual  Date of Interview   Place   xdaysbefore      CountedEvents
       1         2016-07-11        1       2014-09-11         2
       2         2016-05-07        3       2014-07-04         1
       3         2016-08-09        2       2014-03-22         1
       4         2016-01-10        3       2014-09-17         1
```

where `CountedEvents` are the number of events happened in the time frame `Date of Interview - xdaysbefore` and in the same location where the individual i has been interviewed.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (something we can copy/paste into R)?

Comment: So basically, you want to find for a place in `B.df` , number of events that occurred in `A.df` in the range of `xdaysbefore to Date Of interview` at the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` on every row of `B.df`.

Take a subset of `A.df` where places are equal. Check if the `Date` in `A.df` is within the range of `Date_of_Interview` and `xdaysbefore`

```
B.df$CountedEvents <- apply(B.df, 1, function(x) {
    temp = A.df[A.df$Place %in% x[3],]
    length(temp$Date < as.Date(x[2]) & temp$Date > as.Date(x[4]))
 })

B.df
#     Individual Date_of_Interview Place xdaysbefore CountedEvents
#1          1        2016-07-11     1      2014-09-11       2
#2          2        2016-05-07     3      2014-07-04       1
#3          3        2016-08-09     2      2014-03-22       1
#4          4        2016-01-10     3      2014-09-17       1
```

**EDIT**

If you want to access columns with names instead of indexes, you can use

```
apply(B.df, 1, function(x) {
        temp = A.df[A.df$Place %in% x["Place"],]
        length(temp$Date < as.Date(x["Date_of_Interview"]) & 
               temp$Date > as.Date(x["xdaysbefore"]))
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. What if I want to improve it in order to count only events of a certain type?
Let's say that in A.df there is an additional column "EventType" which shows values 1,2,3,4. And I want to count only events of type 1.

Comment: Just change `temp = A.df[A.df$Place %in% x[3],]` to `temp = A.df[A.df$Place %in% x[3] & A.df$EventType ==1`,]

Comment: Since I have many variables in my dataset I would like to invoke them by name. I think there is something wrong in the code below. It produce the variable CountedEvents with no variation just a single value for all rows, that value corresponds to the number of observations in B.df.
Code:
`B.df$CountedEvents <- apply(B.df, 1, function(x) {
  temp = A.df[A.df$Place %in% B.df$Place,]
  length(temp$Date < as.Date(B.df$date) & temp$Date > as.Date(B.df$xdaysbefore))
})`

Comment: @HamidOskorouchi okay..I have updated the answer. Please check if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a combination of `merge` and `aggregate`:

```
# merge into a new dataset
AB <- merge(A, B, by = 'Place', all = TRUE)

# create a logical variable which indicates whether 'Date' falls within the range
AB$count <- AB$xdaysbefore < AB$Date & AB$Date_of_Interview > AB$Date

# aggregate into a count varaible
aggregate(count ~ Individual + Date_of_Interview + xdaysbefore, AB, sum)
```

which gives:

> ```
>   Individual Date_of_Interview xdaysbefore count
> 1          3        2016-08-09  2014-03-22     1
> 2          2        2016-05-07  2014-07-04     1
> 3          1        2016-07-11  2014-09-11     2
> 4          4        2016-01-10  2014-09-17     1
> ```

---

Alternatively you could use the new non-equi join possibility from the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

# convert the dataframes to data.table's (which are enhanced dataframes)
setDT(A)
setDT(B)

# join and count
A[B, on = .(Place, Date < Date_of_Interview, Date > xdaysbefore)
  ][, .(count = .N), .(Individual, Place, Date_of_Interview = Date, xdaysbefore = Date.1)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Individual Place Date_of_Interview xdaysbefore count
> 1:          1     1        2016-07-11  2014-09-11     2
> 2:          2     3        2016-05-07  2014-07-04     1
> 3:          3     2        2016-08-09  2014-03-22     1
> 4:          4     3        2016-01-10  2014-09-17     1
> ```